# WebGL - Width, height parameters passed in validateCompressedTexSubDimensions() function?

Tags: opengl-es, webkit, textures, compression, webgl-extensions

I am working on some compression support in WebGL-Webkit. So I was looking at existing S3TC support provided in WebGLRenderingContext.cpp file in Webkit code. What confuses me is the code written inside "*validateCompressedTexSubDimensions(GC3Denum target, GC3Dint level, GC3Dint xoffset, GC3Dint yoffset, GC3Dsizei width, GC3Dsizei height, GC3Denum format, ArrayBufferView* data)*"
s3tc extension spec says that you should throw an error in your application if:
"* plus  is not equal to texture width*";
Then how is it that in the existing webkit code for the function validateCompressedTexSubDimensions() for S3TC, the code goes on something like this:
 "*if (width - xoffset > tex->getWidth(target, level) {synthesizeGLError("blah blah") }*"
Is this code right? If so, then what is the meaning of "width", and "tex->getWidth()" in the webkit code.
Is width the width of the sub-image or the actual width of the complete tex2D texel array?
And what does the constant "TEXTURE_WIDTH" stand for?
Looking forward to your useful comments :)

Comment: Is this the appropriate forum to ask questions about webkit code? shouldn't you ask on the webkit mailing list?

Comment: Yup you are correct..sorry would post it there..actually i am a newbie in webkit domain and was in a hurry to get answer for this question, so didn't explore that i could also raise the same in their mailing list.